# First bytes of text portable reader (Windows)

Tags: windows, xml, portable

Sometimes I need to open XML files on different PCs

If an XML file is bigger than 100 Mb it takes a lot of time to be opened

I need something like a Bash "head" command

I don't need to read the whole file. I just want to see first 10-30 rows from this file to be sure that this is the file I need

(eg: I see first tags like `<date>14-02-2020</date>`  and can say: "Hey! this is the data I need")
Printing first n-symbols from the file also fits my needs

I need a small and portable windows(or cross-platform) software for this purpose.

P.S. I will consider coding it myself if there is no such software